# Correct Location for Custom Zend_Action_Controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

The ZF Docs reference '[Subclassing the Action Controller](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html)' (bottom of the page), but don't reference a standard place to put the new Action_Controller class.

Application_Module_Autoloader sets up pats for a bunch of things, but never controllers. I guess putting it on `library/APPNAMESAPCE/Action/Contoller` would work. But that seems a bit odd since every other application specific file is stored under `application/`.

Answer (score 3):

The class gets autoloaded like any other class, there isn't a 'standard' place for it as such. So the question becomes, where do you want it to live?

The convention I usually follow in modular applications is to have most stuff in the modules, but register an app namespace and use application/models for 'core' type classes. So in your case, say your app namespace was Wordpress, you'd have:

```
class Wordpress_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

}
```

and the file would live in application/models/Wordpress/Controller/Action.php.

To make this work you'll need application/models on your include path, and you'll want to init the standard autoloader with something like this (in your bootstrap class):

```
protected function _initAutoloader()
{
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->registerNamespace('Wordpress_');

    return $autoloader;
}
```

alternatively you could setup the above in application.ini.

Comment: There are indeed 'standard' places. As mentioned in the question, newer versions of ZF take care of autoloading automatically, mapping not only 'Namespace\_Models\_' to `application/models`, but 'Namespace\_Forms\_' to `application/forms`, and the same for 'dbtable', 'mappers', 'plugin', 'service', 'viewhelper', 'viewfilter'. Sure, I know I can put it in `application/models`, but that's where I put my *models*, not my controllers.

Comment: I am aware of how the resource autoloaders work. My point was that there isn't a standard place for controller base classes, so personally I put it in the model directory (since IMO it isn't a controller, it's just a component used by them). Alternatively you could register a new resource type just for controllers, and have Namespace_Controller_Controller_Action, but that would seem like overkill for what I imagine will be only one class.

Comment: I misread your first line to mean there's not a standard place for the classes you need autoloaded (not just no place for controller classes), my mistake. Seems like `application/controllers` could be used without the extra level (after all 'real' controllers end with 'Controller', so that helps with naming issues). Guess it's something to play with.